# HttpClient .send() throws IOException when running outside the IDE

Tags: java, jlink, jpackage

I try to get the latest release tag of a Github repositiory via HttpClient.
The plan is to send a request to github.com/user/repository/releases/latest and get the uri of the redirect to determine the latest release tag.

When the program is running in my IDE, everything works fine. But for some reasons a IOException is thrown when the program is jlinked + jpackaged.
I allready tried to run it as an admin to rule that out.

My code:

```
  private static String latestVersionTag() {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.NORMAL).build();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest
                .newBuilder(URI.create("https://github.com/{placeholderUser}/{placeholderRepo}/releases/latest"))
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .build();

        try {
            HttpResponse<InputStream> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream());
            String path = response.uri().getPath();
            return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Edit: i ran the jlinked image without packaging to get the stack trace (haven't thought of that before, sorry)

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:576)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:123)
        at launchofexile/com.github.cptblacksheep.launchofexile.UpdateChecker.latestVersionTag(UpdateChecker.java:76)
        at launchofexile/com.github.cptblacksheep.launchofexile.UpdateChecker.checkForNewVersion(UpdateChecker.java:35)
        at launchofexile/com.github.cptblacksheep.launchofexile.UpdateChecker.startupCheckForNewVersion(UpdateChecker.java:28)
        at launchofexile/com.github.cptblacksheep.launchofexile.LaunchOfExileMain.initialize(LaunchOfExileMain.java:285)
        at launchofexile/com.github.cptblacksheep.launchofexile.LaunchOfExileMain.main(LaunchOfExileMain.java:475)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:736)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:691)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:506)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:482)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:679)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.unwrapBuffer(SSLFlowDelegate.java:529)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:433)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate.java:268)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$LockingRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:205)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:149)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:230)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: What do you mean by this? `jlinked + jpackaged`

Comment: By jlinked + jpackaged i mean that i used jlink to create a runtime image und jpackage to create an installer for the program

Comment: @CptBlacksheep Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also add the full complete exception message and stacktrace you get to your question.

Comment: so, to clarify, packing your java program using jlink and jpackage throws `IOException`? or is it at runtime after the packing? what the exception message says?

Comment: If you print a stack trace where you catch the exception it may help.

Comment: It's my program at runtime that throws the IOException when executing the given code piece. When i execute the same code piece in intellij it works without problems. I can't really provide a stack trace as it only happens outside the IDE. I tried to catch all possible exceptions that .send() can throw seperately (and showed a joptionpane with a corresponding error message) to find out it's the IOException that gets thrown.

Comment: Which modules are included in the `jlink`-built image? I remember someone else once having a problem with missing cryptographic modules, causing handshakes (or something) to fail.

Comment: @Slow You might be right, i use apaches maven jlink plugin to jlink, so it should theoretically include all relevant dependencies. But when i go after the legal folders in the image there's only java.base, java.datatransfer, java.desktop, java.net.http, java.prefs, java.xml. nothing cryptographic

Comment: Try configuring the plugin to include `--add-modules jdk.crypto.cryptoki,jdk.crypto.ec`.

Comment: Including jdk.crypto.cryptoki solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The handshake is failing because your custom run-time image is missing the necessary cryptography modules. Adding:

```
--add-modules jdk.crypto.cryptoki,jdk.crypto.ec
```

When running `jlink` should fix the problem.

I'm not sure if you absolutely need *both* modules, or which of the two is the necessary one if you don't need both. It's also possible one of them `requires` the other, causing the other to be implicitly pulled in.